# Expected browser binary location with Robot Framework & Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, robotframework

I get this error when running :

```
Open Browser    http://google.com    ff
```

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

(Edge and Chrome works fine)

It did work before but after some ff update it stopped working. I tried to reinstall without success.

Where the problem might be? (geckodriver?)

This log does not help:(geckodriver-6)
1659673686066   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:57574

Comment: Is there some log that might show more information where it goes wrong?

I tried to add C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\FIrefox.exe to path but it did not help. (and previously when it worked it was not there also)

Comment: Does this error message mean that Firefox is not found? It is installed to default location

Answer (score 0):

Better use win64 driver instead of win32 :( :) :)